# C# Find byte pattern from current stream position, return new byte position

Tags: c#, parsing, byte, sequence, filestream

I'm writing a small program that replaces specific byte information at their appropriate offsets.

Currently, the code sends FileStream to look for the desired offset given from a Data Grid entry, but I'm wanting to then read the next 50 bytes for a byte sequence/pattern and then set the current FileStream's position to the starting point of the found pattern.

Here is my code as it sits now.

```
            using (var fs = new FileStream(yOBJFile.FileName, FileMode.Open,FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                fs.Position = Int32.Parse(rowp.Cells[4].Value.ToString(), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);

                string BytePatternString = "675F66537065634C6576656C";
                byte[] BytePattern = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(BytePatternString);
            }
```

I would very much appreciate any help aiding me in a solution.

Thank you.

Comment: Never Never put bytes into a string.  It doesn't work.  Ascii encoding will remove non printable characters so always use UTF8.

Comment: I never knew that. Thanks!